# Sumar dos valores de un formularo

Tags: php, javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola a todos.
tengo el siguiene caso, necesito hacer un formulario tipo factura en donde puede agregar mas lineas a la factura que las que se dan pordefecto (1).

Cada linea tendrá espacios para Nombre Medicamento, Unidades, Costo Unitario y Costos total, se supone que el costo total seria las unidades x costo unitario..

Ya tengo el formulario, ya logro que inserte una fila con las divisiones que les comento, ya puedo salvar esto a la base de datos, osea casi todos me lo hace. lo que NO he podido hacer es calcular automaticamente el costo total que les comente anteriormente.

Esa parte puede parecer sencilla y lo es, encontré el siguiene coódigo para realizar lo que necesito y me funciona porque lo probé por aparte y resulto bien.

```js
function cal() {
  try {
    var a = parseInt(document.f.num1.value),
        b = parseInt(document.f.num2.value);
    document.f.sum.value = a + b;
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f">
  <p>Número 1: <input type="number" name="num1" value="0" onchange="cal()" /></p>
  <p>Número 2: <input type="number" name="num2" value="0" onchange="cal()" /></p>
  <p>Suma: <input type="number" name="sum" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></p>
</form>
```

Ahora, si todo esta bien cual es el problema, me parece que es esto pero no estoy seguro, yo para agregar las nuevas lineas lo hago por medio de este codigo, por este require_one (el cuan funciona bien).

```
<div id="productos">
    <?php require_once("InputDinamico.php") ?>        
</div>
```

Esto lo que tiene es los siguiente

```html
<div class="lista-producto">
 <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="row list-group-item">        
        <div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="pro_nombre[]" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="pro_cantidad[]" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="pro_pre_unitario[]" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="pro_costo_total[]" /></div>        
 </li>
 </ul> 
</div>
```

lo que creo es que al ejecutar este codigoel JS le pasa algo y no funcino para sumar esos dos valores. ahi es donde me parece que esta el problema, pero ya le he dado caeza por horas y no le llego, por eso acudo a ustedes.

Es un poco complicado pero espero haberlo explicado bien.

Gracias de antemano por su ayud

Comment: podrias subir el html y js completo? o por lo menos una parte funcional para poder ayudarte mejor. Gracias

Comment: Si las filas se añaden dinámicamente, podría ser que tienes que delegar el evento. Te dejo este fiddle que puede que te sirva de ayuda: https://jsfiddle.net/vf4d56n3/

Comment: No entendí bien el segundo código HTML que muestras. ¿Se trata de agregar productos nuevos o son productos que ya existen en una base de datos o pueden ser ambas cosas? La cuestión es que sería quizá mejor tener algo así como un mini módulo de agregar productos donde se muestre una lista de los ya existentes en la base de datos (y/o una opción de agregar uno nuevo si fuera el caso). Creo que tener claro ese aspecto es determinante para una solución óptima.

Comment: Que paso con los otros comentarios que estan aqui ?

Comment: Buensa noches... no seporque desaperecieron los comentarios que tenia con otro compañero sobre este tema, alguna idea? Alguna ayuda con respecto a la pregunta realizada?

Comment: Hola, para continaur con esta misma pregunta... ya logré agregar nuevas lineas dinámicamente, y ya logre que la cantidad se multiplica por valos unitario y ponga el resultado en un imput
`function multi(valor){
  m1 = document.getElementById("txt_campo_1").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("txt_campo_2").value;
  r = m1*m2;
  document.getElementById("spTotal1").value = r;
}`
Lo que me esta pasando es que al agregar una nueva fila dinámicamente no me realizaa la multiplicación, solo me hace el caulculo de la primera linea pero no de las restantes, alguna sugerencia? Gracias